# How to center a paragraph vertically in a div without the two divs overlapping?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't figure out how to vertically center my name in this div. It's supposed to be the homepage on my website. The PgOne div is supposed to take up the height of the person's screen, so the name is supposed to be centered on the div (main), which is just below the navbar on PgOne.

The problem with the solutions that work is that when the window is really small vertically, it runs into the navbar.

I've tried these in CSS under .main and .name

```
flex-grow: 1; 
display: flex; 
align-items: center;
```

^^ This works, but when the window is really small vertically, it runs into the navbar.

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
position: absolute;
```

^^This works, but when the window is really small, they overlap.

```
padding-top: 10%; padding-bottom: 10%;
```

^^ Doesn't work.

```
display: table-cell; 
text-align: center; 
vertical-align: middle;
```

^^ Doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
<div class=PgOne>

    <div class="navbar">
        <div>
            <p>HOME</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>ABOUT</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>EXPERIENCE</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>RESUME</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>CONTACT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=main>
        <div class="name">
            <p>FirstName<br>LastName</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


CSS

.navbar div {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 18%;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;

    width: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    padding: 20px;

    /*flex-grow: 1; 
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;*/
}
```

Comment: Along with the copious [repetitive answers](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) I'm sure will be provided remember to reset/override your `<p>` element from the browser default stylesheets margins to get it vertical center in the parent; `p { margin: 0 }`

Comment: You can troubleshoot this kind of thing easier with adding background-color to the .main and the <p> so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name *is* vertically centered within its container DIV. You just didn't set any height to the div (`.main`), so the DIV itself doesn't span the full page height, if that's what you are after. In my adaption of your code below I used `calc` for the height (expand it to see it), but the actual method depends on what you really want/need, i.e. on the full code of the page.

```css
.navbar div {
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  width: 18%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #555;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background: #eee;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class=PgOne>

  <div class="navbar">
    <div>
      <p>HOME</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>ABOUT</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>EXPERIENCE</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>RESUME</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>CONTACT</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=main>
    <p>FirstName<br>LastName</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this is that now, it no longer centers horizontally.

Comment: Oh well, you only wrote about centering vertically in your question, and with your original code it didn't center horziontally, so I didn't pay any attention to that, but simply add `justify-content: center;` to achieve that ( I edited my answer code accordingly).

Comment: Thank you! It worked. The only thing is, when the window is really small, my name runs into the navbar and they overlap. I've changed my question to include that

Comment: Just use media queries with a smaller font size for height below a certain value... `@media screen and (max-height: 400px) { .main p { font-size: 18px; } }` or similar

Answer (score 1):

After removing your absolute position `transform`, I made `PgOne` a flex parent and added a `min-height: 100vh`, the full viewport height. Next, I apply `flex-grow: 1` to `main`, instructing it to take up as much vertical room as possible. I don't add anything to `navbar`, so it takes up whatever vertical space is remaining. To show it's taking up the correct space and vertical centering, I've added a background color on `main`.

http://jsfiddle.net/j8meqtvp/

```css
.PgOne {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar div {
    margin-top: 13px;
    margin-right: 1%;
    width: 18%;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.main {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
```

```html
<div class=PgOne>

    <div class="navbar">
        <div>
            <p>HOME</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>ABOUT</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>EXPERIENCE</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>RESUME</p>
        </div><div>
            <p>CONTACT</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class=main>
        <div class="name">
            <p>FirstName<br>LastName</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```